# enqueing stylesheets for a child theme in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, function, stylesheet

I have created a child theme in wordpress off of a parent theme called bigpont. I am also using woocommerce as well on the site. I had enqued my child theme style sheet and have noticed it loads twice and I'm not sure why. I am also wondering how I can get it to load so it overrides the woocommerce style sheet. Here is the code I'm currently using in my functions.php file:

```
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {

$parent_style = 'bigpoint-css'; 

wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/base.css' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
  get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
  array( $parent_style ),
  wp_get_theme()->get('Version')
  );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles');
```

and here is how the stylesheets are being loaded on my site
[image]
It seems to load as 'bigpoint-default-css' and then again as I added it "child-style-css'

****UPDATE: I found the answer to my css being loaded twice, in my parent theme's functions.php file it being called in with :

```
wp_register_style('bigpoint-default', get_stylesheet_uri(), '1.0');
```

so I used this to undo that:

```
  function unhook_parent_style() {

  wp_dequeue_style( 'bigpoint-default' );
  wp_deregister_style( 'bigpoint-default' );

  }
  add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'unhook_parent_style', 20 );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking at the file `class-wc-frontend-scripts.php` it looks like WooCommerce enqueues it scripts/styles with the default priority of 10.

```
public static function init() {
        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array( __CLASS__, 'load_scripts' ) );
        add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', array( __CLASS__, 'localize_printed_scripts' ), 5 );
        add_action( 'wp_print_footer_scripts', array( __CLASS__, 'localize_printed_scripts' ), 5 );
    }
```

So if you enqueue your scripts with a lower priority they it will load after the WooCommerce style and overwrite that stylesheet as the file will be loaded after the WooCommerce one lower down the HTML document.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles', 100 );
```

I would need more information to debug what is happening with the duplicate stylesheets though.

Comment: thanks Andrew that helped with loading my stylesheet after the woocommerce css. i found this in the parent themes functions.php file and I beleive it's where the other loading of my css file is happening: wp_register_style('bigpoint-default', get_stylesheet_uri(), '1.0'); but I'm not sure how to deal with that in my own functions.php file.

Comment: I can't answer that question if I can't see all your code.

Comment: i figured it out and posted it in my question, thanks for helping out a wordpress newbie :)